# date and time to be displayed in UI

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have fetched date and time from the Database. I am passing the fetched value to `date()`. In local machine the date and time is displayed correctly. But in Server it is showing the Local machine date and time.(I want the time, which is fetched and passed into `date()`, not the local time.

My code is:

```
function lastUpdatedTime(obj) {
    var val = new Date(parseInt(obj.LastUpd.substr(6)));
    lastdate=val.toLocaleString();
}
```

obj---->fetched from database

object returns a bigint value and i want to convert it to the following format:

Monday, January 13, 2014 4:49:59 AM

Comment: Yes obj is json only.

Comment: what you want to with the date. you want to print it somewhere ??

Comment: Date object is not needed if you just want to show it somewhere on the page. just append the fetched data

Comment: I want to print the date. In local machine it works fine. The value passed into date() is a BIGINT value. To change that to date format only I have used date()

Comment: I want to display in a specified format as follows: Last updated on: Monday, January 13, 2014 4:49:59 AM

Comment: may be you are getting wrong timestamp in json. because that should not matter in server or local. i checked it works fine both in local and server:::

var val = new Date(134221342134);
val.toLocaleString();
console.log(val.toLocaleString())

Comment: can you post the json snippet

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(timeInfo),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            lastUpdatedTime(data);
        }

Comment: {
 "LastUpd":"1231313"
}

it should be something like this

Comment: in quick watch it shows as follows:LastUpd "/Date(1389571869110)/"

Comment: that is todays date. so it means you are getting wrong timestamp from your returned json.. check the code which returns the json. and what do you mean by local system. is it localhost ?

Comment: Whenever I update the content, it stores the last updated date and time. just before I updated. so it shows todays date.

Comment: what i understand from your question is you are querying database using dotnet and converting the returned data into json and parsing it with javascript using ajax.

Comment: Yes... that is correct....

Answer (score 0):

check if the below code is returning something or not:

```
obj.LastUpd.substr(6);
```

because if the above line returns nothing then it will be the current date time.

it would be helpful if you can add the json snippet.

**Update:**
Do the date conversion stuff on server side and have a try.

Comment: it is returning value. Local machine everything works fine. but in server only prob

Comment: so please post you returned json code(just part of it is fine)..because i checked your code on server and local both works fine..

Comment: nope.... I'm fetching and displaying. tats it.. but in server it fetches local time. tats only the problem.

Comment: how could that be possible server time local time are different or what?

Comment: first check the db if you have the correct latest value there.

Comment: server is in some other place(redmond). I am logging in using remote machine.. My prob is that it should display the date which is passed. but it displays local machine time...

Comment: database I am having correct value only. else in local machine how I am getting the correct date and time as in the database

Comment: Yes. both local and server are pointed to same server database

Comment: can you try timestamp to date conversion part in server side code itself and add it to json. This would be better i guess. have a try

Comment: the value returned in json itself differs both in local and remote... In local it returns correct value in DB.. but in remote it returns current date and time..

Comment: Thats weird need some demo to figure it out

Comment: if i see the issue lively then i can help. because it seems weird which should not happen